# Flutter setState double value not change?

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm using Dart Flutter for develop apps but It's not working?

```
void _goLondon() {
    setState(() {
        mapLat = 23.7807777;
        mapLng = 90.3492857;
    });
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We would like to assist you, but you would have to provide more description as to how exactly it is not working. Did you call the _goLondon method somewhere within your code? What is supposed to happen when these values change?

Answer (score 0):

with only this code is not possible to know what is going on.

mapLat and mapLng can not be const or final
and your mapWidget need to be inside a StatefullWidget